# Positive alternative of Clique?

Tags: word-usage

I'm planning to develop a brand identity, which will be creating revenue through clicks! The whole idea is ethical, no deceptive tricks involved.

I want to add a gimmick to traditional boring form of articles. To do so I will create a group of characters affiliated with actual article writers. These characters are more of anime style fighters ..... like samurai, ninja, boxer etc ....

The name I came up with is " Scarlet Clique "

The reason behind the name is that I will draw the characters in charcoal pencil sketch form with a cloth element of scarlet color. As they are a group of character having a common purpose or aim so I thought to call them clique instead of clan.

I feel that "Scarlet clique" rhymes better than " scarlet clan " does. Also "clique" will point to "click" which is an important aim!

I now have some concerns about "clique" as after reading a previous answer about the word here on this forum. I learned that the world "clique" can have a negative meaning which I am afraid might be an issue in future!

Is there a Positive alternative for the word Clique?

Please ignore any language mistakes as English is not my first language :)

Comment: Did you check a thesaurus? Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "more balanced in rhyme" because those two words don't rhyme at all.

Comment: My bad, I believe I wanted to say clique sounds more stronger than clan ... as scarlet does, but maybe it is based on my personal feel of sounds! Anyways thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**a plural title coupled with a descriptive adjective** , can strongly suggest, when capitalized, that the name must be a "group","team", "squad", "clan" etc.

**Scarlet Scribes** might fit *this alternative approach.*

Again, "scribes" is NOT a word for a generic group ... however the "Scarlet Scribes" capitalized as a proper name, leaves little doubt that it is a group.

For example, you have groups like the "Power Rangers" and the "Ninja Mutant Turtles" or even a construction like "The Ghostbusters"

The word "scribes" more firmly connects them to the writers you mentioned they represent.

--

In a similar fashion of using a proper name to create a unsaid group:

The **Scarlet Select** might be an alternative that meets your desire to emphasize "clicks" ... The term "select team" is common in international sports and the word alone means "elite"

> ***select*** adjective  [from Cambridge Dictionary site](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/select)
>
> the best of its type or highest in quality:
>
> *select fruit/school*
>
> *a select group of people*

Comment: Thank you so much dear! Your suggestion solved my problem, in fact "Scarlet Scribes" matched with the original concept. I don't think there could be a better combination!

Answer (score 1):

*Squad*. From [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squad):

> 2: a small group engaged in a common effort or occupation

It has positive contemporary connotation. See [*squad goals*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Squad%20Goal). Also, "Scarlet Squad" has a nice ring, I think.

Comment: Thanks, yup they go well. Scarlet Squad ...... or maybe I can keep it simple to "Scarlet Circle" ?

Comment: Sure you could. For some reason, "circle" sounds sort of nefarious to me, whereas "squad" is more playful.

Comment: Thanks Evan .... I also feel squad makes a better pair with scarlet .... Cheers! :)

Comment: While it is longer, if you wanted to encompass the "clicking" idea in this good alternative you could call them the "Scarlet Select Squad".

Comment: Thanks @Tom22 , Your suggestion is also fine but I feel it's a bit long. I'm trying to chose between "Scarlet Squad" and "Scarlet Circle"

Could you please suggest any other alternative of clique, clan, squad etc?